# Asset Entry - Reuse prevoius rows columns A-D

Tags: excel

We have an excel spreadsheet which we enter our hardware Info.

eg
Manf \ Model \ TYPE \ ASSET \ SN

Now the lads enter the 1st 4 columns by hand and then use a scanner for the SN.  On quite a few occasions the actual hardware is the same. So after scanning the 1st item it will jump down to the next row.  I would like then for them to scan the next item so it inputs the SN from the Scanner but as columns A \ B \ C \ D are blank I would like it to copy the info from the previous row.

I was playing with this code but the auto convert lower to upper works but will not copy previous rows 1-4 if there is a value in current row 5

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
Application.EnableEvents = True
If Target.Column <> 5 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Row = Cells(65536, Target.Column).End(xlUp).Row Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range(Cells(Target.Row - 1, 1), Cells(Target.Row - 1, 4)).Copy
Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 4)).PasteSpecial      xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: I've got my spreadsheet to automatically convert lower to upper.